# In a Kendo ComboBox, how do I make an input element gain focus?

Tags: jquery, focus, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I'm trying to give focus to the input element of an item in the drop down list when the corresponding rename button is clicked. I've tried the [jQuery .focus() function](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) but the combobox simply closes without actually giving focus to the text input box.

I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible to allow the user to type into a text input box in this scenario.

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/MattDietrich/DfxBD/

```
$('.licenseHoverButton.rename').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevents combobox from closing
    var input_elem = $(this).siblings('.licenseName');   
    alert('Rename: ' + input_elem.val());

    /*
    Make input_elem have focus so that the user can type a new name. 
    The combobox must remain open.

    ie. input_elem.focus();    
    */
});
```

**EDIT: A Clarifying Example**

Here's a Fiddle that demonstrates my problem by contrasting with a checkbox: http://jsfiddle.net/MattDietrich/cWLQy/

- Notice how you can freely check/uncheck the checkbox but you can't edit the text
  boxes.

How can I give focus to (and edit) the text boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) support admin, this is not currently supported. I'll update this answer if/when I hear that the issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is not currently supported, BUT according to my experience of working with Telerik controls there are dozens of things that are not supported but very needfull. As a rule wanted behavior can be achieved by various of tricks and hacks, and this case is not an exception.

I wrote common fix, that enables focusing any elements within:

```
var _ignoreClose = false;
var funcClose = combobox.close;
combobox.close = function(){
    if (_ignoreClose) return;
    funcClose.call(combobox);
};
combobox.input.focusout(function(){
    _ignoreClose = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
        _ignoreClose = false;
    });
});
// set our handler as most priority
var evt = $._data(combobox.input[0]).events['focusout'];
evt.splice(evt.delegateCount, 0, evt.pop());
```

Also, if you want to make elements within clickable:

```
combobox.list.off('mousedown');
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8zuygey4/1/